# Geodesic curvature of a line on a surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Problem:
Find the geodesic curvature of the line $t = s ^ 2$ on the surface $$r = p(s) + t  p'(s)$$ where $s$ is a natural parameter.

P.S.
I know how to find geodesic curvature for non natural parameter, but I do not understand how to use this formulas in this case. Any close example? Or any formulas and how to use them.
Here is formula $$k = (1/|r'|^3)*(r'',r',n)$$ where n - normal vector.(Maybe it will help)

Comment: Post what you know specifically and ask a specific question where you get stuck in your work. We cannot magically know what techniques and concepts you know and what you don't. Moreover, is there not a typo in your definition of the surface? Maybe proofreading would be in order, as well.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm only do not know how to put vectors here. it must be above $p$ and $r$

Comment: You can put vectors with \vec, but that is not the issue. Most ruled surfaces are of the form $r = p(s)+tq(s)$ with $p$ and $q$ different. If this is not a typo, the surface is just a cone $r=tp(s)$ to start with. Regardless, show your work and attempts.

Comment: @TedShifrin found mistake, you was right, thank you!

Comment: @TedShifrin  Made some edits. Is it needed to show my solutions to the close examples but with non natural parameter? Can i show it with fotos of my work?

Comment: For starters, your use of $r$ in that formula is for the parametrization of a curve, and yet you have $r$ representing the position vector of the surface. This is an unpleasant calculation, but I assume you've computed the Frenet frame for curves that are not arclength parametrized before. Why can you not compute derivatives of this parametrized curve and find the surface normal?

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually, I am used to surfaces like this $r={ucos(v), usin(v), av}$ and for them i can do it, but now I stuck.

Comment: So ... Here you have $s$ and $t$ as parameters instead of $u$ and $v$. Rename the variables if you want.

Comment: @TedShifrin And what by what parameter derivative in this case? ($r'$ or $r''$). Is it $s$?

Comment: @TedShifrin And $|r'|$ what does it mean in this case? I know that it is vector length but where is that vector? Sorry for so many stupid questions, but i really want to understand it better.

Comment: Let's get rid of the letter $s$, since it's too easy to forget and think it means arclength. Write $r(u,v)=p(u)+vp'(u)$ and $\alpha(u) = r(u,u^2)$. Prime in your formula now means differentiation with respect to $u$. By the way, I don't know what book you are learning from,  but you might find my differential geometry text (linked free in my profile) helpful.

Comment: @TedShifrin I mean that surfaces that i used to have no + or - or something like this. If $r$ is a vector in my formula where is here my vector? Can you please show what is $r' = $?

Comment: Do you have the final answer by any chance?

Comment: @666User666 I will post here answer when i understand it.

Comment: Does the book say what is the ambient space (like R^2, R^3 etc)? If not, you can think like this: $p(s)=( x(s) , y(s) , z(s)..)$

Comment: @666User666 Okey, but what $r'$ then? it's like $r' = p'(s)+2sp''(s)$ or what?

Comment: Don't forget basics. Product rule?

Comment: @TedShifrin   Okey, ther is mistake (it's already 3 a.m. in my country, sorry) but if it's right, what should i do with lenght of vector? ($|r'|$)

Comment: @666User666 And now how can i find triple product?

Comment: @666User666 It uses vectors too $(r'',r',n)$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132301/discussion-on-question-by-mathic-geodesic-curvature-of-a-line-on-a-surface).

Comment: @mathic have a look now

Comment: @666User666 You mean we can not get "exact value" because of natural parameter? So we leave this X (multiplication) and it's okey?

Comment: @666User666 Okey some time to think and now i understand how to find "exact value" thank you! And some funny thing: only one teacher in my city can solve it, but he gave me this task...

Comment: Exact value of what are you referring too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: The geodesic curvature is the component of acceleration  in the tangent plane of the surface for  a particle travelling at unit speed along the curve.

Hint 2: Derivative of curve with Arc lenght parameterization gives unit tangent.

Arc length is given as $S(t) = \int_{t=0}^t  \sqrt{v(t) \cdot v(t)} dt$, meaning $ S'(t) = \sqrt{v(t) \cdot v(t)}$ . If t is arc length, then $S'$ means derivative of arc length with respect to arc length which is one. This makes $\sqrt{  v \cdot v} = 1$ meaning $|v|=1$

---

For understanding the calculation , let's take $p(s)=  \left( x(s) , y(s) , z(s) \right)$, then:

$$ r(s,t) = \left( x(s) + t x'(s) , y(s) + t y'(s) , z(s) + t z'(s)  \right)$$

To find the equation of curve on the surface, we replace plug in the relation of input variable in domain:

$$ F(s)= = r(s,s^2)  = \left( x(s) + s^2 x'(s) , y(s) + s^2 y'(s) , z(s) + s^2 z(s) \right)= p(s) + s^2 p'(s)$$

We can now differentiate:

$$ \frac{dF}{ds} =(1+2s) p'(s) + s^2 p''(s) = (1+2s) (x'(s) , y'(s) , z'(s) )  + s^2 ( x''(s), y''(s) , z''(s) )  \tag{1}$$

$$ \frac{d^2 F}{ds^2} = (1+4s)p''(s) + s^2 p'''(s) + 2 p'(s) \tag{2}$$

For the normal, go back to the equation of surface:

$$ r(s,t)= p(s) + t p'(s)$$

$$ \partial_s r \times \partial_t r = (p'(s) + t p''(s) ) \times ( p'(s) ) = t p''(s) \times p'(s)$$

The unit normal is given as:

$$ n= \frac{p''(s) \times p'(s) }{| p''(s) \times p'(s) |}$$

(1) is velocity, (2) is acceleration and above is normal.